# Magento requestShippingRates argument

Tags: php, magento

I am a bit confused about a function:

```
public function requestShippingRates(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)
{
    /** @var $request Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request */
    $request = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_request');
    $request->setAllItems($item ? array($item) : $this->getAllItems());
}
```

I know that `$item` is an arrangement, but what is this `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract`?

Comment: It is the concept of "Type Hinting". It tells you about your parameter type. $item is refer to Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

For Type Hinting see the [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

As stated in an example on the referenced Page:

```
<?php
class C {}
class D extends C {}

// This doesn't extend C.
class E {}

function f(C $c) {
    echo get_class($c)."\n";
}

f(new C);//C
f(new D);//D
f(new E);//throws exception
?>
```

The reason Magento is doing this is because you can use one method for both getting the shipping rate for one or all shipping items (when passing invalid data).